# Call a URL without DNS Entry from Azure Function .Net

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, hosts

From an Azure function i need to call a webservice that is not under a published DNS entry. Typically on a server I own i would simply update the hosts file. Is there an equivalent way to do this with an Azure Function. I'm using C# .net and right now 4.61 v1 Function because i was having trouble getting v2 to deploy.

Comment: Are you using an HttpClient to call that service? you can use the IP address you'd put in your hosts file, then set the host header `Host: <yourServiceName>`

Comment: highly recommended to update 4.61 to .netcore 2, especially since you are on v2